# Freaky Bash command line completion results

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, kubuntu

I un-tar-ed a file and it had a directory called "~something".

Without thinking I typed "cd ~" and hit tab to have bash complete the name.  Instead of getting the "~something" result I expected I got a whole list of things starting with "~".  Some of them are a little disconcerting.  Things like: ~pulse ~sys/ ~daemon/ ~kernoops/      ~mysql/ ~root/ ~syslog ~libuuid/ ~rtkit/ ~usbmux

I deleted the tar directories and tried from another directory with the same results.

I did I a find on a couple of these starting from / down and found nothing but I am confused where and why Bash came up with this list and wondering if perhaps I have been rooted.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` indicates the current user's home directory. `~username` indicates that user's home directory. bash sees the `~` and assumes that you want some home directory on the system. If you want a literal "~" then you need to escape it.

```
cd \~<Tab>
```

Comment: But I don't have any home directories with the names bash came up with.  Nor any files with those names in my own home directory. I don't understand how bash came up with the list.

Comment: Every user has a home directory. Not all are under `/home`.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I ran cat on /etc/passwd and the names I saw are in the file.  But their home directory entries point to directories that don't exist e.g. /home/kdm

Comment: I have assume Bash is taking a shortcut and listing home directories from `/etc/passwd` without necessarily verifying that the directories actually exist.